# частота анализа текста C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Не понимаю, как сделать, что бы подсчитывало не только русские букву но и английские буквы.

```
public static void LetterRatio(string text, DataGridView dataGV1)
        {
            var Alphabet = Enumerable.Range('А', 32).Select(x => (char)x).ToArray();
            string txt = Regex.Replace(text, "[#-.?!)(,: ]", "");
            txt = txt.ToUpper();
            Dictionary<char, double> Analysis = new Dictionary<char, double>();
            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Alphabet.Length; i++) 
            {
                count = 0;
                foreach (char letter in txt) 
                {
                    if (letter == Alphabet[i]) 
                        count++;
                }
                if (count > 0) 
                {
                    Analysis.Add(Alphabet[i], Math.Round(((double)count / txt.Length),2));
                }
            }

            var items = from pair in Analysis
                        orderby pair.Value descending
                        select pair;

            dataGV1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGV1.Columns.Clear();


            var column1 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column1.HeaderText = "Буква";
            column1.Name = "letter";
            column1.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

            var column2 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column2.HeaderText = "%";
            column2.Name = "percent";
            column2.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

            dataGV1.Columns.Add(column1);
            dataGV1.Columns.Add(column2);

            dataGV1.Columns[0].Width = 30;
            dataGV1.Columns[1].Width = 30;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<char, double> pair in items) 
            {
                 dataGV1.Rows.Add(pair.Key, (pair.Value * 100) + "%");
            }

        }
```

Comment: `...что бы подсчитывало не только русские букву но и английские буквы...` - тогда надо бы расширить диапозончик здесь `var Alphabet = Enumerable.Range('А', 32)`.

Comment: `...есть проблема в подсчёта соотношения символов` - какая проблема? Если вы хотите получить ответ, старайтесь подробнее описывать проблему, а не просто фиксировать ее факт, который очевиден пока только вам.

Comment: я её решил, прости что не дал конкретики, осталось только одна проблема с определением латинских букв.

Comment: Я решил все две проблемы, спасибо что поставили на место. :)